# Charging Li-Ion cells

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have 6 18650 Li-Ion cell from a very old Dell laptop. Unfortunately I could not find any info about them from their markings.

They were connected as 3S2P with a total of 11.1V and 4700mAh.

Measured each cell individually and all read 3.7V or very close.

I'm charging one with a bench supply starting with 4.15V and 1A. Read somewhere that 0.5C would be safe, and if I got it right 1C=2.35A.

Now, the weird thing is, that after it gets down to about 300mA charging current, it starts increasing. What's going on? Should I be worried?

Thanks.

Comment: The current increased to 470mAh and the cell started to get warm so I stopped it.
Seen some scary videos with Li-Ion gone wrong. Don't want to risk it. :)
2 mins later the cell voltage dropped to 3.95V so I guess it can't hold charge very well.
I did test it on a constant current load (500mA) and I got around 1Ah after a previous charge up to current increase.

Comment: That behavior is strange. I work with new lithium ion cells quite often and this phenomenon does not normally occur. Are these cells just bare cells? You have stripped them out of the pack, so that there is no protection circuit anymore? Did you double-check the power supply output voltage with a volt-meter? If the cell acceptance climbs as voltage increases, I think the cell is defective. But you should think if there is some other explanation, such as defective circuitry or incorrect meter reading, etc. Do not continue to use defective cells unless you are prepared for them to vent/ignite.

Comment: Yes, I removed the cells from the circuit.
I am measuring the voltage at the cell, not at the supply.

The current increases about 100mA if I increase 0.01-0.02V, but drops quickly (1-2mA/s). E.g. 4.15V/350mA, 4.17V/450mA.

Comment: What was the cell voltage when the current increased to 470 mA?

Comment: Current started increasing at about 4.12-4.13V

When it got to 470mA voltage was 4.17V

Comment: Definitely not normal. If you limit the charge voltage to 4.2 or below, in a normal cell, the current will drop lower and lower. When the current reaches some lower limit (such as C/20) the charge is terminated to prevent over-charging.

Answer (score 1):

You may have cells that need to be cut off at 4.1 V or lower. Set your supply to a  voltage that causes close to zero current through the cell and then slowly increase the voltage while watching the current and temperature. Don't leave the cell unattended and have a bucket of sand or appropriate fire extinguisher nearby.

Answer (score 0):

You should most definitely be worried; as a general rule, any abnormal behaviour when dealing with li-ion batteries is a cause for concern.

It's possible that your cell has developed an internal short; the reasons this happens are beyond my means to explain properly, but over-discharge and age are among the contributing factors. Perhaps these cells are from a pack that hasn't been charged in a few years?

If you're brave, you could test this by increasing the cell's State-of-Charge (SoC) by a fixed amount of energy several times, letting it sit for a known spread of time intervals and then measuring the capacity. But I wouldn't read this paragraph as an endorsement or a recommendation. ;)

Comment: The cells haven't been charged for 5 years at least. But when I got them out of the pack they each read 3.7V.

Comment: I have a 3.7V Panasonic Li-ion cell that charges similarily. My cell charges to ~4.06V & then starts to heat up--but, regardless of how long I allow it to charge, the in circuit V will never increase above 4.08V. If I let it charge, it just continues to heat up without any increase in V. My best guess is that there is some kind of defect somewhere within the lithium foil in the cell that prevents charge acceptance.  Possibly a micro-short of some kind, because internal resistance decrease since charge current increases after decreasing steadily until that point in the charging process.

Comment: All of the other cells from the same batch (6 total from the same batch) all charge up to 4.2V & essentially charge down to @ 50 mA before charge termination is finished. That indicates to me that the 4.08V cell has an obvious defect. The cell can still be used elsewhere (with some risk, obviously) for low current needs, but charging it requires careful monitoring or a heat sensor (thermistor) to prevent a catastrophic failure from occurring during charging.

Answer (score 0):

If each cell individually had 3.7V or very close, it means it should be in relatively good shape. there should be no problem if the charge current increased more than you specified.

But...the current increase problem may indicate overheating of a cell. If the cell does not have full capacity anymore and you try to fully charge it, you may experience exactly what you describe: at a voltage point below max charge level, the current will start to increase and the cell will start to overheat. Not stopping the charge at that point may cause excessive over-heat and even fire.

So make sure they don't overheat. That's the only thing you need to worry about. If the cell reaches max charge voltage (4.2...or 4.15V in your case) there is nothing to worry about.